# Double-not of an empty regex literal (!!//) is false, is this a parsing error?

Tags: regex, ruby

In Ruby, only `false` and `nil` are falsey; everything else is truthy. You can use two `not` operators  to check an object's truthiness:

```rb
!!false   # false
!!nil     # false
!![]      # true
!!{}      # true
!!''      # true
!!0       # true
```

But then I found that empty-regex literal `//` is falsey, but as a variable, it's truthy!:

```rb
!!//        # false!
not not //  # false
x = //
x.class     # Regex
!!x         # true
```

I think this is a quirk of the parser. How can I ask the parser what it's doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not just applicable to empty regex literal, but rather all regex literals;

```
!!/(.*)/
=> false

x = /(.*)/
!!x
=> true
```

At first this appeared to be an issue with the way the regexp is being constructed

```
!!Regexp.new('')
=> true
x = Regexp.new('')
!!x
=> true
!!//.freeze
=> true
```

But digging deeper, this appears to be the cause:

```
!!//
=> false
$_ = 'b'
!!//
=> true
```

Setting '$_' back to nil will reset the outcome. The value for `$_` is set from `Kernel.readline` or `Kernel.get` siblings. In a new console:

```
Kernel.readline
a
"a\n"
!!//
=> true
```

So instantiating a Regexp object with `//` appears to match it against the value of `$_`

Comment: _"So instantiating a Regexp object with `//` appears to match it against the value of `$_`"_ That seems right because after `$_ = 'b'`, `!!/b/` is also true.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'm not 100% sure, but my idea is that Ruby is doing the next thing when you run `!!x`

```rb
puts !!// # this is doing a phantom .match(nil), like below, so, returns false
x = //
puts !!x.match(nil)
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why `puts !!x` prints `true` and why `puts //` doesn't print `false`.

Comment: `!!//` does a `!!Matchdata`, but `!!x` does a `!!Regexp`. That is my though.